# SQL Server 2008 R2 Query Last Successful Database Backup For All DBs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

Is it possible to query the last successful backup date (and perhaps the type of backup) of each database in SQL Sever 2008 R2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Database_Name,
CONVERT( SmallDateTime , MAX(Backup_Finish_Date)) as Last_Backup, 
DATEDIFF(d, MAX(Backup_Finish_Date), Getdate()) as Days_Since_Last
FROM MSDB.dbo.BackupSet
WHERE Type = 'd'
GROUP BY Database_Name
```

Comment: Add an INNER JOIN to MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases (join on columns msdb.dbo.backupset Database_name, master.dbo.sysdatabases name) and you can omit databases backed up but since dropped.

Comment: Would this include databases that have never been backed up?

Comment: @jl01: Good catch!

Comment: @KyleBrandt: This would only include databases that are part of the backup set.  See:  http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/using-msdb-backup-tables

Comment: @OliverAsmus: Okay, so  I think I can include those by just doing a RIGHT OUTER JOIN to sysdatabases, group on master.dbo.sysdatabases.name,  and adding a `OR TYPE IS NULL` to the WHERE clauses

Comment: @KyleBrandt: Good idea - I'll add that to my script too!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as long as the history data is still in msdb database. The following block of code will get your the last 100 backups including full, differential and log backups.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    s.database_name, 
    m.physical_device_name,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, s.backup_start_date,
    s.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' ' + 'Seconds' TimeTaken,
    s.backup_start_date,
    CASE s.[type]
    WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
    WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential'
    WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
    END AS BackupType,
    s.server_name,
    s.recovery_model
    FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id 
    WHERE s.database_name = DB_NAME() -- Remove this line for all the database
    ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC, backup_finish_date
    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Powershell this is what I have.
If you have SQL 2008 SMO DDLs on your computer use line 1.  If you have SQL 2005 SMO delete line 1, remove the # and use line 2.  If all else fails delete both lines 1 and 2, remove the # and use line 3.
Replace Your_Server_Name_Here with the name of the server you're checking.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" -EA Stop
# Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" -EA Stop
# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | Out-Null
$srvObject = = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'Your_Server_Name_Here'
$srvObject.Databases | Select Name, LastBackupDate, LastDifferentialBackupDate, LastLogBackupDate
```